# Selling Seforim to Gentiles Online

Tags: halacha, jewish-books, internet, transactions, hacham-ovadia-yosef

The Yalkut Yosef [246:55](http://www.or-hanetzach.co.il/wp-content/uploads/2011/05/arochyosef.html#HtmpReportNum0922) says:

> וכן אסור למכור לגוי ספרי קודש, כמו תנ''ך וכדומה

Besikum: you can't sell holy books to gentiles.

What about online sales? Must you ask the buyer via email if he is Jewish?

CYLOR!!!

Comment: Does sifre kodesh mean sifre tora, mezuzot, etc. or printed books like chumashim, mishneh tora, igrot Moshe, etc.?

Comment: What's with the 'cylor' thing?

Comment: Contact your local orthodox rabbi

Comment: @YaakovKuperman, some people here feel it is necessary to indicate with each question that, of course, for halachic decisions you consult your rabbis.  Others take that as given.

Comment: Awesome. Somehow I feel that people who would take crowd sourced halakhic opinions aren't going to be deterred by an acronym though. :)

Answer (score 3):

We have an online [ספרי קודש](http://www.hamadaf-y.co.il/) Store called The Jewish Bookshelf, and we received a payment  from a Professor from Egypt that bought a number of religious books. We wasn't sure but the name wasn't Avraham/Ytshak/Yaakov/David... It wasn't a very jewish name.

We asked Rabbi Shlomo Chaim Hacohen Aviner, and he ruled not to sell him the books, so we refund him and said we cant send books to Egypt...

Hope it helps... Nissim.

Comment: I prefer it over doing Averot :) Thats the Halacha, and it is not determined by popularity...